# Pass mongoose connection to module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing a Node module which whould perform queries to MongoDB.

My module should take as parameter (when I init it with `new MyModule(db)`) the MongoDB connection and use it inside it.

I was using standard MongoDB without any NPM module and I was passing in my db variable the connection to MongoDB. Now I'm switching to Mongoose and I can't find a way to pass the Mongoose connection to my module.

I don't want to initialize the Mongoose connection inside my module because I want to share it with my tests and with other modules.

How can I do? I've tried passing `mongoose` to my module but it doesn't work "is not a function".

**Edit:**

After reading the reply of @Neil Lunn I'm posting this sample of my module:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    /**
     *  various requires
     */

    function TopicManager(dbURI) {
        if (!(this instanceof TopicManager)) { return new TopicManager(dbURI); }
        mongoose.connect(dbURI);
    }

    TopicManager.prototype.save = function (topics, done) {

        var Topic = new mongoose.schema(
            {
                title: { type: String },
                slug: { type: String, index: { unique: true } }
            },
            {collection : "topics"}
        );

        /**
         * Use monguurl on "slug"
         */

        mongoose.update(
            {title: topic.title},
            {upsert: true},
            function (err, numberAffected, raw) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                return done(null, raw);
            }
        );    
    };

    module.exports = TopicManager;
})();
```

It doesn't work because when I use it I get `undefined is not a function` when it runs `new mongoose`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a default [Mongoose connection](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
```

If you want to open multiple connections you can use `createConnection`:

```
var dbconnection = mongoose.createConnection ('uri,uri');
```

This connection object can then be used for creating/retrieving models that are scoped only to this connection.

The Mongoose connection object has multiple events on which you attach handlers. You should check out the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection) for the full list of handlers you can use.

To get you started, a basic approach would be:

```
// log connection errors
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

// wait for opening the connection
db.once('open', function () {
   // do something once connection to the MongoDB is open
});
```

If you open your connection using `createConnection`, you need to use it when creating models:

```
// dbconnection is created using createConnection
var MyModel = dbconnection.model('MyModel', MyModelSchema);
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking you don't do this. The mindset is a little different with mongoose than working with the native driver in it's raw form, and there are plenty of things helping under the hood to make things work a bit more seamlessly without diving into the gory details.

So the basic approach is when you define your "schema" and "models", these are bound to the default connection instance. Unless you have a specific reason for binding to another connection, this is what you should follow:

So you would have a Schema and model definition:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    "name": String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model( "Model", mySchema, "collection" )
```

Where the "collection" part is optional otherwise the "model" name in the first argument is put to standard rules, usually lowercase and pluralized.

Then in your other code listing, you pull this in with require:

```
var Model = require('./models/mymodel.js');
```

And use your model objects as mongoose permits:

```
Model.find({ "field": "name"}, function(err,models) {

});
```

So it allows a bit more abstract handling than is done with the basic driver as the "models" themselves know how to bind to connections, or are otherwise explicitly bound to the connection you want as an optional parameter.

Comment: Thank you I've edited my question adding informations of my attempt with your method... I think it should work but it doesn't, may you help me?

Comment: @FezVrasta You seem to be going into a little "JavaScript good practice" overkill. You should try keeping it "clean and simple" as I did in the example code.

Comment: I don't understand how to keep it "simple"... I need to init the connection and use it in my prototypes and your example doesn't give me clues to do it... :(

Comment: @FezVrasta loose the `function()` wrapper. All you need here when working with node and `require` is just basic JavaScript as I have listed. The JS file you require should not have anything much more than exactly how I have typed it out here.

Comment: Remove the wrapper would require remove the strict and would expose the mongoose to the entire application... I don't think it's a good idea. There's not a better solution? Maybe use a mongodb connection to initialize a Mongoose instance?

Comment: @FezVrasta The connection is "meant" to be exposed to your entire application. This is good practice as it is what what `mongoose.connect` does, but not really a "global", more explaination. If you actually look closely though, all you are really doing in pulling in a local `var` for the model via require. This is not client side JavaScript. node works differently. Just do it that way. It works. No dangerous globals. Trust people who build the libraries and don't second guess until you know better yourself.